# How can I enable breakpoints in Eclipse/CDT

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using `Eclipse 3.5.1` on `Ubuntu 9.10`, with `CDT 1.0.0.200909110608`

If I right-click the left margin for a context menu, `Toggle Breakpoint`, `Enable Breakpoint` and `Breakpoint Properties` are all grayed-out.

How can I enable these?

Apart from breakpoints, the debugger and the rest of CDT are working fine.

Comment: Are you building with debugging symbols enabled?

Comment: Yes, the CFLAGS are '-g'.  I had to manually set CFLAGS to '-g' as they were '-g -O2' by default.  This caused variables to be optiised away.

Should Eclipse be setting CFLAGS correctly for me?

I have tried creating both a 'GNU Autotools' project and a plain 'Executable/Hello World ANSI C Project'.  They both suffer from this problem.  I'm using plain C, not C++.

Comment: Are you able to set breakpoints if you load the resulting binary into command-line gdb?

Comment: Yes, breakpoints are fine in gdb.

Reading symbols from /home/chris/workspace.xt65/debug_test/src/a.out...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005ec: file debug_test.c, line 14.
(gdb) break 18
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4005fb: file debug_test.c, line 18.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/chris/workspace.xt65/debug_test/src/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at debug_test.c:14
14 int main(void) {
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, main () at debug_test.c:18
18  for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) {

Comment: I'm not an expert on Eclipse, but it seems like a GUI setup/use issue.
Try reading through and following http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_o_debug.htm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check Run->Breakpoint Types->C/C++ Breakpoints

Comment: Yes, that's just what I'd missed.  It's a bit strange, 'C++ breakpoints' was the only option and it was already selected, but clicking made breakpoints work.  Thanks, Chris.

Comment: In debug configuration, unchecked "Stop on startup at". It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off "Skip all Breakpoints". That worked for me.