# Eclipse Run-->Breakpoint Types-->None Available

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake

I am encountering the same problem that many others have in Eclipse, as is apparent by the many questions.  I found an answer in [this question] ([How can I enable breakpoints in Eclipse/CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929141/how-can-i-enable-breakpoints-in-eclipse-cdt))

So I checked my Run-->Breakpoint Types and there were none available.  How do I change that?

BTW:  I don't believe this should matter, but I have set up my Eclipse project *by hand* and added the CMake files.  I have to run CMake to generated dependencies in the code.  But by creating my Eclipse project *by hand* I should be able to debug it.  So, again, how do I add Breakpoint Types?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate it when I post a question and then find the answer!

I fixed this problem by following the instructions in [the Eclipse Community Forums Question](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/333528/), which took me to [CDT/User/FAQ Eclipsepedia - Enable the C/C++ Tracepoint functionality](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_can_I_trace_my_application_using_C.2FC.2B.2B_Tracepoints.3F) that told me what to do.

It worked!  Yay!  I hope this information helps others.

Comment: I don't hate it, it's cute  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow - How are you doing, my SO friend?  You're crazy funny!  :-)

Comment: HEH!  :)  Here's -17 of funny http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255366/contention-should-points-be-completely-eliminated-on-so